# ProgressDialog with custom theme

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, progressdialog

I have an activity with a theme associated (in AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<activity
        android:name=".BenchTestActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".HomeActivity"
        android:theme = "@style/AppTheme.CaeTheme">
```

The AppTheme.CaeTheme contains nothing (at the moment) but AppTheme is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

(colorPrimary is dark blue)

Now I'm defining a progressDialog in above mentioned activity.

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BenchTestActivity.this);
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.ProgressDialog);
```

and here the ProgressDialog style:

```
<style name="ProgressDialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorBackgroundProgressDialog</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#e6e6e6</item>
</style>
```

colorBackgroundProgressDialog is a light gray. I was expecting to obtain that color as background for my Progress Dialog but that's not what it's happening (the background color is a dark blue, colorPrimary). So the background on the activity theme is winning. So, how can I set a custom color for the Progress Dialog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah its due to the theme applied to the activity, please check it again

Comment: I know. But how can I set it correctly? I need that theme on the activity. What is the way to customize the progressDialog's background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the constructor that [accepts `theme` as argument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#ProgressDialog(android.content.Context,%20int)) and pass appropriate theme.

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.MyProgressDialogTheme);
    progressDialog.show();
```

In `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="MyProgressDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- override attributes here -->
</style>
```

Comment: @Massimo, most possibly you have applied incorrect theme. Updated the answer, checked, works as expected.

Comment: No,  using this constructor the progressDialog doesn't appear. I don't know why but... the pair progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BenchTestActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.ProgressDialog); should be the same. But, as I said in my answer, this style doesn't override the activity's theme.

Comment: `should be the same` It is not the same.

Comment: Ok. What was causing the error was the tag <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>. Removed it and all start working.

Answer (score 0):

in your styles.xml

```
<style name="Custom" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog">
    <item name="DialogTitleAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="DialogTitleText">Loading……</item>  
    <item name="DialogSpotColor">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <item name="DialogSpotCount">4</item>
</style>
```

and in your activity,java:

```
SpotsDialog spotsDialog = new SpotsDialog(Context,R.style.Custom);
spotsDialog.show();  //where you want
spotsDialog.dismiss(); //where you want
```

and add Dependency

```
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
```